# How to give a model object an order (or index), which can be reassigned?

Tags: django, django-models

Say you have an ordered list. You order the list based on a model field called "index". So the first item has an index of 0, the second has an index of 1 and so on...

The index is unique to that model object.

How would you implement this?

I want to be able to create more instances of the model object, where the index is assigned to the next available index (add the object to the end of the list). And then be able to reorder the list so that if you change the index of an object, all the following object's indexes increase by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an IntegerField that increments itself you can use the id. It's unique for that model and Django generates it automatic. And you can order by this using

**inverse:**

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

**Normal order:**

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

If you just have a field that contains auto-increment-index don't need to create another one only if you can modify it, but if this index is unique you cannot edit it to prevent duplicates. Si I would use the id `MyModel.id`

Here you have the documentation for [.order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

Comment: Can you reassign the id? So if I want to change object 5's id, to the id of 1, does object 1's id then become 5?

Comment: Nope, you can't do that, now I see why you want that field. Well, for now I can only help with the order_by(). Continue searching...

Answer (score 0):

There is no field that does that automatically. Have you looked in to using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders) for this? You could hook up a signal that detects an index change, and triggers a function that updates the index of every object whose current index is greater than the one being removed/changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may ave to rethink your schema because if you change the index of your first element in the list which has lets say 1 million elements, you are gonna update 1 million objects! You may save for each object its left and right "neighbour" and create a method to get the list.